# stack data between languages

Tags: c++, assembly, types, stack

Lets say for example, I push a large amount of data onto the stack using some assembly code. My question is, is it possible to manipulate this data in a language such as c++ by passing the address of the stack pointer to the c++ program(or some other way)? If so, how would c++ handle this data? Meaning, how would I determine the data types in c++?

Comment: I would say don't use the stack for that "communication". Use usual parameter passing/memory for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, provided of course that you use the calling convention properly, so that the data is well clear of any regions of the stack that the C++ code is using as stack. Stack memory is just memory, and as far as the code receiving this pointer is concerned, there's no difference between pushing some values onto the stack, or moving the stack pointer (i.e. creating an array/struct on the stack) and then writing the values into the space you've made, or just dynamically allocating some memory and putting the values in. Your assembler push instructions put the values there in some particular layout, is all.

You can't determine the data types. On x86, for example, two 32 bit `int` values side-by-side are *exactly the same* as a 64 bit `long long` value. That's why calling conventions specify the layout of parameters on the stack, and require that the caller and the callee both know (and agree) the order and types of the parameters.

Of course you can provide extra information which allows the callee to work out the data types. For example, the first parameter to `printf` is (a pointer to) the format string, and by parsing the format string the callee knows what the types of the remaining parameters are for this particular call, and then can read them using the varargs macros.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would all need to run in the same process as well. But couldn't you just typedef a struct in the c++ to determine the data type and append a header to the info you are putting on the stack indicating how the data is laid out.

Comment: yes, and most likely if I was going to pass this data over the stack, I would have a formal format that would need to be pushed on, and the c++ program would read it off, in that format.